# What am i doing wrong in this LINQ statement?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am studying Linq to xml and i am reading a xml file using linq.. I used the following method,

```
public void getbooklist(string Path)
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Path);
    var books = new book in xdoc.Elements("book")
                 select book; 
}
```

and my xml file looks like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
     <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
     <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
     <genre>Computer</genre>
     <price>44.95</price>
     <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
     <description>
      An in-depth look at creating applications
       with XML.
     </description>
  </book>
  <book id="bk102">
     <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
     <title>Midnight Rain</title>
     <genre>Fantasy</genre>
     <price>5.95</price>
     <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
     <description>
       A former architect battles corporate zombies,
       an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
       of the world.
    </description>
 </book>
</catalog>
```

and when i tried to execute the method i get an error

`A new expression requires (), [], or {} after type`... What am i doing wrong?

Comment: could you please google before you post questions like these.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You code should be something like this:

```
  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(Path);
    var books = from b in xdoc.Elements("book")
                 select b;
```

Comment: Hows that different from what he's already got? Edit: OHHH he has new instead of from. I was too busy looking at 'b' and 'book'